# JSF 2.2 ui:repeat varStatus attribute missing

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.0, I am trying to use ui:repeat but the new `namespace` of `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets` does not seem to provide the varStatus attribute, is there another way to get the status of ui:repeat.

Comment: Hm, according to the documentation it should still be there: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html . Did you actually try to use it and got an error? If so you may have stumbled upon a regression bug.

Comment: yes I have and what is a regression bug ?

Comment: google and wikipedia are your friends. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression .